# Array of Radio buttons directly related to array of Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Specifically I have a range of 3 Radio Buttons, before a range of 5 checkboxes, with a calculator field attached to give different values depending on how many checkboxes are selected.

Example:

> Radio Button: 1
>   Radio Button: 2
>   Radio Button: 3
>
> checkbox: a
>   checkbox: b
>   checkbox: c
>   checkbox: d
>   checkbox: e

- If 1-2 checkboxes are selected, value is 50 each checkbox
- If 3 checkboxes are selected, value is 125
- If 4 checkboxes are selected, value is  155
- If 5(all) checkboxes are selected, value is 170

---

I have this functionality working properly with this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {

    if($('input[type="checkbox"]:lt(5):checked').length == 1) {
        greeting = "50";
    } else if ($('input[type="checkbox"]:lt(5):checked').length == 2) {
      greeting = "100";
    } else if ($('input[type="checkbox"]:lt(5):checked').length == 3) {
       greeting = "125";
    } else if ($('input[type="checkbox"]:lt(5):checked').length == 4) {
        greeting = "155";
    } else if ($('input[type="checkbox"]:lt(5):checked').length == 5) {
greeting = "170";
    };

    document.getElementById("input_53_34").value = greeting;

});
});
</script>
```

Here is what I need and am not sure of the best way to accomplish:

- If radio button 1 is selected - treat checkbox fields as normal
- If radio button 2 is selected - check checkboxes a,b,c
- If radio button 3 is selected - check checkboxes a,b,c,d,e (all)
- If checkbox selection is changed to quantity(length) 2 or 4, switch
  back to radio button 1
- If checkbox selection is a,b,c, or ALL, switch to radio button 2 or 3
  respectively

Basically, radio button 2 is 3 specific checkboxes (a,b,c) while radio button 3 is all checkboxes

THANKS TO TINYGIANT - 
CLOSEST TO WORKING - [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vux4n79g/3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a lot of consecutive `if` statements, use [switch statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch).

You have to attack this from two directions.

To make the radio buttons affect the checkboxes

- Attach a click handler to the radio buttons
- Reset all checkboxes
- If the 1st radio button is clicked, do nothing
- If the 2nd radio button is clicked, check the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd checkboxes
- If the 3rd radio button is clicked, check all checkboxes

To make the checkboxes affect the radio buttons.

- Attach a click handler to the checkboxes
- Reset all radio buttons
- If all checkboxes are checked, select the 3rd radio button
- If the 1st, 2nd and 3rd checkboxes are checked, select the 2nd radio button
- If any other combination of checkboxes are checked, select the 1st radio button

```js
$('input[type=radio]').click(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked',false);
    switch(this.value) {
        case "2":
            $('input[type=checkbox]:nth-child(1), input[type=checkbox]:nth-child(2),input[type=checkbox]:nth-child(3)').prop('checked',true);
            break;
        case "3":
            $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked',true);
            break;

    }
});
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
    var checked = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked');
    $('input[type=radio]').prop('checked',false);
    console.log($('input[type=checkbox][value=1]:checked').length);
    if(checked.length === 5) {
        $('input[type=radio][value=3]').prop('checked',true);
    } else if( $('input[type=checkbox][value=1]:checked').length 
           &&  $('input[type=checkbox][value=2]:checked').length 
           &&  $('input[type=checkbox][value=3]:checked').length
           && !$('input[type=checkbox][value=4]:checked').length) {
        $('input[type=radio][value=2]').prop('checked',true);
    } else {
        $('input[type=radio][value=1]').prop('checked',true);
    }
});
```

```html
<div id="radios">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="1" checked>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="2">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="3">
</div>

<div id="boxes">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" value="1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" value="2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" value="3">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" value="4">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" value="5">
</div>

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```